# How to Add Logging to MVC4 WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a `[LoggedApiCall]` filter for a `Get()` on an `ApiController`
According to this: [ASP.NET Web API ActionFilter example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307333/asp-net-mvc-4-webapi-actionfilter-example)

I have created a `System.Web.HttpFilters.ActionFilterAttribute`.
The override allows for `OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)`

I cannot seem to find a way to get the IP of the caller from the `HttpActionExecutedContext`

Perhaps I am going about logging every API call the wrong way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We use the following filter which we add to `HttpConfiguration.Filters`. Some code:

```
internal class LoggingFilter : IExceptionFilter, IActionFilter
{
    private readonly ILog log;

    public LoggingFilter(ILog log)
    {
        if (log == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("log");
        }

        this.log = log;
    }

    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    Task IExceptionFilter.ExecuteExceptionFilterAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (actionContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
        }

        this.log.Error(string.Format("Unexpected error while executing {0}", this.BuildLogEntry(actionContext.ActionContext)), actionContext.Exception);
        return TaskHelpers.Completed();
    }

    Task<HttpResponseMessage> IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        if (actionContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
        }

        if (continuation == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("continuation");
        }

        if (!this.log.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            // no point running at all if logging isn't currently enabled
            return continuation();
        }

        string logEntry = this.BuildLogEntry(actionContext);
        IDisposable logContext = this.log.DebugTiming("Executing {0}", logEntry);

        Task<string> requestContent;
        if (actionContext.Request.Content != null)
        {
            requestContent = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(requestResult => string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestResult.Result) ? "N/A" : requestResult.Result);
        }
        else
        {
            requestContent = TaskHelpers.FromResult("N/A");
        }

        return requestContent.ContinueWith(
            requestResult =>
                {
                    this.log.DebugFormat("{0}, Request = {1}", logEntry, requestResult.Result);

                    return continuation()
                        .ContinueWith(t =>
                            {
                                Task<string> responseContent;
                                if (t.IsCompleted && t.Result.Content != null)
                                {
                                    responseContent = t.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(responseResult => string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseResult.Result) ? "N/A" : responseResult.Result);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    responseContent = TaskHelpers.FromResult("N/A");
                                }

                                return responseContent.ContinueWith(
                                    responseResult =>
                                        {
                                            using (logContext)
                                            {
                                                this.log.DebugFormat("{0}, Status Code: {1}, Response = {2}", logEntry, t.Result.StatusCode, responseResult.Result);
                                            }

                                            return t.Result;
                                        });
                            }).Unwrap();
                }).Unwrap();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds log data about the request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionContext">Data associated with the call</param>
    private string BuildLogEntry(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        string route = actionContext.Request.GetRouteData().Route.RouteTemplate;
        string method = actionContext.Request.Method.Method;
        string url = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
        string controllerName = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        string actionName = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        return string.Format("{0} {1}, route: {2}, controller:{3}, action:{4}", method, url, route, controllerName, actionName);
    }
}
```

We use log4net, you can replace the `ILog` implementation with whatever you see fit. `ILog.DebugTiming` is just an extension method that uses a Stopwatch to get elapsed time for each call.

Edit:
This post [Get the IP address of the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host) has details on how to get the IP address of the remote caller.

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: The link you sent works:
private string GetClientIp(HttpRequestMessage request)
  {
   if (request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
   {
    return ((HttpContextWrapper)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress;
   }

   if (request.Properties.ContainsKey(RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name))
   {
    RemoteEndpointMessageProperty prop;
    prop = (RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)request.Properties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];
    return prop.Address;
   }
   return null;
  }

Comment: It seems like Mike's answer is the better choice - where you can inject the actual logging implementation or even the inbuilt web api log framework if so desired (and thus prevent doubling up of effort).

Comment: We investigated the `ITraceWriter` bits but it seemed very difficult to correlate start and end timings and there seems to be a distinct lack of production strength implementations in the community to guide writing your own. We decided the above approach was simpler.

Comment: Now that the ASP.NET team has released a reference implementation of `ITraceWriter` I'd highly recommend that people don't use this answer - use the NuGet package at http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing/ or write a custom implementation based off the code at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/91f78bc347fa#src/System.Web.Http.Tracing/SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter.cs

Comment: @DeanWard: Sorry to warm this up, but am I correct that neither solution can log the actual verbatim request? Even the trace writer just exposes the regular, non-rewindable stream so I have no chance of reading the request content, correct?